# How to cycle through class instances in a predefined order in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I am looking for a clean way to read data from all of my instances of a class dealing with embedded chips **in the order t hey were declared** with a single function I could declare whether or not as a part of the class itself.

The function would need to check how many instances of the class were constructed in my program (I think I figured this part out), then check what is the order they were declared, but I am not sure my strategy is the best approach:

```
class input_shift_reg
{
public:
    input_shift_reg();
    int shift_ID; //keeps count of which instance # this is
    int data; // stores data from the chip when read
    int *ptr_to_data; //
    };

input_shift_reg::input_shift_reg()
{
    shift_ID = nb_of_input_shift_reg_objects++;
}

void inputShiftSnapShot() //take a 74hc165 snapshot of the data on the 74hc165 and // transfer it via SPI protocol to the arduino
{

    PORTD &= ~(1 << loadPin); //ask the chip for a snapshot (this part is working alright)
    delay(1);
    PORTD ^= (1 << loadPin);

// This is the part that needs to transfer varying on the number of class instances. 
for(int i = 0; i < nb_of_input_shift_reg_objects; i++)
{
    // HERE IS MY PROBLEM: it needs to transfer to the data member of each inst in right order
    data = SPI.transfer(0x00);
}
}
```

So I simply need a way for the inputShiftSnapShot() to check what is the value of shift_ID member of all the class instances created, and SPI.transfer() for each data member in the right order.
example:

```
    input_shift_reg shift_1();
input_shift_reg shift_2();

inputShiftSnapShot(); // this would transfer to shift_1.data first, then to shift_2.data second.
```

How can I do that?? Thank you!

Comment: Could you (possibly) have a **static** member of the class that is a `std::vector` of pointers to each instance? I could elaborate if you think this is feasible.

Comment: order of declaration or of creation? maximum what you can do about first is order of instantiation which isn't same because compiler passes through things in particular order, that would be the quirky trick "static counter". Order of creation would be real-time and you have to have a static list of instances within class

Comment: Note that  line `input_shift_reg shift_1();` isn't variable declaration, it's a declaration of function `shift_1` returning type `input_shift_reg` and taking no parameters. Most Vexing Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using a static container of instance pointers.

One thing to keep in mind is that every construction/destruction of `input_shift_reg` will have side-effects, namely, updating the `s_instances` container.   That is, if your existing code copies these around, passing them by value into functions, you would have many updates to the `instances` deque.

Another potential issue to be careful about is a reëntrancy-like bug if you create/destroy `input_shift_reg` objects while iterating over the instances container.

```
template <typename T>
class tracked
{
    static std::deque<T*> s_instances; 

public:
    static const std::deque<T*>& instances() { return s_instances; }
    static std::size_t number_instances() { return s_instances.size(); }

protected:
    tracked() 
    { 
        s_instances.push_back(this); 
    }

    ~tracked() noexcept()
    { 
        auto it = std::find(s_instances.begin(), s_instances.end(), this);
        assert(it != s_instances.end());
        s_instances.erase(it);
    }
};


class input_shift_reg : public tracked<input_shift_reg> {
   /*  ...  */
};

void inputShiftSnapShot()
{
    // Perform snapshot.
    PORTD &= ~(1 << loadPin); 
    delay(1);
    PORTD ^= (1 << loadPin);

    for (input_shift_reg* reg : tracked<input_shift_reg>::instances())
    {
        // Use `reg` to update instance.
        reg->set_data(...);
    }
}
```

If you don't want the complications of static members, you could make the deque of pointers an ordinary member variable, and force callers to create `input_shift_reg` by calling some `create(...)` function in a pool-like object.  In that case, you would want to make the objects non-copyable and non-movable, so that the pool doesn't get out of sync with objects.