# C++: Keeping track of class objects

Tags: c++, oop

I defined a C++ class and numerous objects of that class get created during my program's runtime.

I need a `get_object_by_name` method.

This is what I would do in python:

```
class Person():
    all_instances = []
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 
        self.all_instances.append(self)
    @classmethod
    def get_obj_by_name(cls, name):
        for obj in cls.all_instances:
            if obj.name == name:
                return obj
```

How can I do that in c++?

Comment: You might record them in a `std::map <std::string, MyClass>`

Comment: `static std::vector` member variable?

Comment: Class variables from Python have equivalent in C++ as `static` members, but are you sure you want to do that? It sounds like a bad design that should be solved in some other way.

Comment: A *similar* (but not really duplicate) with an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142588/10871073).

Comment: One possibility could be to have a factory class to create the objects as shared_ptr and store them on creation as weak_ptr within the factory (optionally cleaning up from time to time), but it's a bit of a hack, only works for heap objects and adds the overhead of the shared_ptr.

Comment: Are you using C++11?  You could use type_name.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Why is that considered bad design?

Comment: @Sky It violates Single Responsibility rule - your class does something it's designed to do **and** it stores instances of itself. Also the use case behind such implementation usually has a *bad smell* as well. I'm not saying it's necessarily bad (missing info on that), but it's worth to be double checked.

Comment: *I defined a C++ class and numerous objects of that class get created during my program's runtime* -- And what about temporary copies of the object?  How do you count those?  Bottom line is that C++ is not Python -- trying to keep track of object counts will more than likely become unmaintainable unless your code controls how the objects are made.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no such feature as `all_instances` in python.

You have to manage this yourself.

First you need to store your different objects of the class in a container (e.g. `std::list<Person> persons`.

The `get_object_by_name` would look like this

```
Person & get_object_by_name(const std::string &name) {
    for (auto & person : persons) {
        if (person.get_name() == name) {
            return person;
        }
    }
}
```

`Person` needs to have a method `get_name()`. Alternatively, you can overload the operator `==`. `get_object_by_name` needs access to `persons`. Thus it is a good idea to put them into a class

```
class Persons{
  public:
    Person & get_object_by_name(const std::string &name);
    // constructor to fill persons
    // method to fill persons

  private:
    std::list<Person> persons;
};
```

As SPD pointed out the choice of the container is not trivial. If you would use and `std::vector` and it grows over time it will cause a re-allocation and thus all references returned are invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either **unordered_map** (hash map, requires C++11) or **map** (rbtree) to simulate Python's dictionaries.

```cpp
class Object {
public: // for simplicity. You will want ctor, getters and setters instead.
    std::string name;
    // other fields...
};

std::unordered_map<string, Object*> objects;

Object * get_obj_by_name(const std::string &name) {
    auto map_iterator = objects.find(name);
    return map_iterator == objects.end() ? nullptr : map_iterator->second;
}
```

Keep in mind that there is **no automatic memory management in C++**, so you need to store your objects somewhere to prevent memory leaks or dangling pointers. If you want `objects` to *own* the objects, then replace raw pointer with unique_ptr (or shared_ptr depending on use-cases):

```cpp
std::unordered_map<string, std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, this kind of feature does not exist in C++ and you have to code it yourself. You already have some examples of how to achieve it by defining external storage class and keep track of the objects by yourself. Below is another approach that delegates the responsibility of objects tracking to the `Person` class itself. Additional assumptions:

- you can only use parametric constructor (or remove `explicit` keyword to make it converting constructor)
- names of Persons must be unique
- you will be careful and you will not try to call `delete` on objects allocated on the stack

```
class Person
{
public:
  /* for example simplifity I delete all the other CTors */
  Person() = delete;
  Person(const Person& other) = delete;
  Person(Person&& other) = delete;
  explicit Person(const std::string& name): name_(name)
  {
    std::cout << "Person(" << name_ << ");" << std::endl;
    if (all_instances_.count(name_) != 0)
    {
      std::cout << "Person with name " << name_ << " already exists" << std::endl;
      throw std::runtime_error("Person with that name already exists");
    }
    all_instances_.emplace(std::make_pair(name_, this));
  }
  ~Person()
  {
    std::cout << "~Person(" << name_ << ");" << std::endl;
    all_instances_.erase(name_);
  }
  static Person* get_person_by_name(const std::string& name)
  {
    if (all_instances_.count(name) == 0)
    {
      std::cout << "Person with name " << name << " does not exist" << std::endl;
      return nullptr;
    }
    return all_instances_.find(name)->second;
  }

private:
  static std::map<std::string, Person*> all_instances_;
  std::string name_;
};

std::map<std::string, Person*> Person::all_instances_;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Person p1("person1");
  try
  {
    Person p2("person1");  // exception
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  {
    Person p3("person3");
    Person* p4 = new Person("person4");
    new Person("person5");  // lost pointer, but later we get it from the map
    delete p4;
    // p3 out of scope
  }
  auto person5 = Person::get_person_by_name("person5");
  delete person5;
  auto person1 = Person::get_person_by_name("person1");
  if (person1) std::cout << "Person1 still exists" << std::endl;
  auto person3 = Person::get_person_by_name("person3");
  if (!person3) std::cout << "Person3 does not exist anymore" << std::endl;
  return 0;
  // p1 out of scope
}
```

Expected output:

```
Person(person1);
Person(person1);
Person with name person1 already exists
Exception: Person with that name already exists
Person(person3);
Person(person4);
Person(person5);
~Person(person4);
~Person(person3);
~Person(person5);
Person1 still exists
Person with name person3 does not exist
Person3 does not exist anymore
~Person(person1);
```

Example verified with valgrind.